When a participle phrase follows a prepositional phrase, what is the participle phrase modifying?
Per title, when a participle phrase follows a prepositional phrase, what is the participle phrase modifying?
For example, in:

Jim tripped, falling to the floor.

"Falling to the floor" modifies "Jim".
Now, if I change the sentence to include an adverbial phrase:

Jim tripped with a shout, falling to the floor.

Is "falling to the floor" still modifying "Jim", or is it now modifying "shout"? If this is a misplaced modifier, or technically correct but confusing, how might I rephrase the sentence?
Also, would the same apply if the participle phrase was a gerund or infinitive phrase? Thank you.

I think I would prefer "Jim tripped, falling to the floor with a shout".

When a participle phrase follows a prepositional phrase, it is usually modifying the noun or pronoun in the prepositional phrase.

Jim tripped, falling to the floor.

"Jim" is the only noun. Jim tripped and he fell to the floor. Nothing else in this sentence is capable of falling.
In examples where there is more than on noun in the prepositional phrase, the participle phrase would modify the main subject, for example:

The firework exploded in a shower of sparks, glowing brightly.

This would mean the firework glowed brightly, which probably isn't what one would want to say. To show that the sparks were bright you would instead say:

The firework exploded in a shower of sparks that glowed brightly.

Your example of "Jim tripped with a shout, falling to the floor" is therefore fine, because modifying the main subject is exactly what you want.

Yes, it might be worth mentioning that these are a way to avoid: He tripped and fell to the ground. The firework exploded etc. and glowed brightly. It's a style mechanism.
